# Remove first element of an array in React useState hooks?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a state like so:

```js
const [array, setArray] = useState([])
```

I know I can use below code to add an item to an array:

```js
setArray(oldArray => [...oldArray, item])
```

How can I remove the first element of this array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
const arr = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4']

console.log(arr.slice(1))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
const names = ['Luke', 'Eva', 'Phil'];
var [first, ...rest] = names;  
console.log(rest); // ['Eva','Phil']
```

[source](https://www.deadcoderising.com/2017-03-28-es6-destructuring-an-elegant-way-of-extracting-data-from-arrays-and-objects-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
setArray(oldArray => oldArray.filter(_,i) => i !== 0))
```